# How to get the button and change its color when datagrid item selected?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid with button included and binded to image as shown. How to get the button control and change its forecolor when the datagrid item is selected.

```
 <DataGrid Name="dgItems" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Width="300" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionChanged="dgItems_SelectionChanged">      
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Name="btnImg" Click="btnImg_Click" Height="160" Width="270">
                                        <Image  Source="{Binding Path=ImgUrl}" />
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

Comment: is there a button for each row in that particular DataGridview ..if so you will need to get at the SelectedItem or Selected Row

Answer (score 0):

As an example you could do something like this..

row.Cells[2].ButtonName.Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

This is pseudo-code but you would have to know the actual cell based on the index this should be enough to get you started could you also post the code behind of the event you are trying to code the button change in..? thanks

Comment: dgItems.ItemsSource = GetAllShirts() //returns a collection of shirt objs. using dgitems.selectedindex I am iterating datagrid items through another external button click xyzbtn_click(). I tried to get the button object from datagrid using dgItems.SelectedItem/dgItem.SelectedIndex but able to get only the Shirt object instead of button object. Now how to highlight/change the button color in datagrid when particular datagrid item is selected through external button clicks.Sorry, want to post the code but it crosses allocated number of words.

Comment: If the button is part of the DataGridView If I am not mistaken there can be a case of hidden fields but there is a way to get at the button that was clicked.. I recall doing something like this when we used telerik controls and I have do writet a javascript function to capture the Click() event of that button.. if you have not gotten this to work let me know and I will open up an old project to paste the code into here..\

Comment: Look at this site as well you need to assign a Click Event to {Binding} from what I have seen http://forums.silverlight.net/t/68070.aspx/1

Comment: Hi DJ KRAZE,I read the forum but its far from my requirement.My app is wpf win app.The datagrid dgItems contains button (btnImg) as shown in xaml which holds some image.But user will not operate the datagrid.To iterate through the datagrid items I use another external button (btnXyZ) using selected index increments.while doing external button clicks the datagrid items scroll, in this proces the selected datagrid item button color should be highlighted. whatever I do I could only get the Shirt object which was assigned to dgItems datagrid but unable to get the button (btnImg) from the datagrid.

Comment: Also pls help to post my code. I am newbie to this site and unable to post in these comments block.